# addEventListener type 'click' actually act like a 'load'

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm currently trying to add a little bit of dynamic on a web page, so I've decide to use Event Listener to load external page without reloading all the page.

Starting this point I've made the following test page content:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><h1>Tagline of the page</h1></li>
                <li id="login"><h1><a href="#" id="authentication">Classic Authentication</a></h1></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id='messages'>
        <p class="title">I'm sorry dave, but you can't access this facility right now!</p>
    </section>
    <script src="/assets/scripts/ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadview(url, id) {
    var xhr_object = null; 
    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 

        xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr_object.open("GET", url, true);

        xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if (xhr_object.readyState != 4) { 
                return;
            }

            if (xhr_object.status != 200 && xhr_object.status != 304 && xhr_object.status !=0){
                console.log("erreur :" + xhr_object.status);
                return;
            }
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = xhr_object.responseText;
        };
    xhr_object.send();
    }
}

var element = document.getElementById('authentication');
var target = document.getElementById('messages');
element.addEventListener("click",loadview('/views/auth_form.html',target.id),false);
```

Here, my problem is coming from my Event Listener which is not doing the job correctly.
I asked him to execute the `loadview()` function when the event `click` is detect on my element identified by the id `'authentication'` BUT instead the Event Listener is executing the `loadview` function as soon as my page is loaded, that sounds a little big awkward for me, so I request for your help.

I know that my code is not clean and quite ugly, especially on the Js part, but I also know that my `loadview()` function is doing the job correctly AND I also know that if I use the old style inline `onclick()` method it's work perfectly.

If you got a clue on this specific topic I'm listening on it ;-)
Every improvement advice is well accept but keep in mind that I first want to solve my problem and not really clean this code.

This code is a test purpose only, so if it's not absolutely clean, I don't really care, except for my personal learning ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addEventListener` requires a **reference** to the function to call. What are you doing is passing the result of the function, which is executed when the compiler reaches that line, as a reference, which is not correct(your function returns `undefined`, since it has no return). You should wrap your code into a function so that it can be passed as a reference to the method:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    loadview('/views/auth_form.html', target.id);
}, false);
```

This is a so called `anonymous function`, you can do with a normal one too:

```
function listenerReference() {
    loadview('/views/auth_form.html', target.id);
}
element.addEventListener("click", listenerReference, false); //passing the reference to the function
```

In this second case when the `click` event is fired the browser will call the function `listenerReference`, since it is the listener which was appended to the event. Note that this approach is different from the `on+event` one, since `addEventListener` can add a lot of listeners on the same event *easily*, while `on+event` requires more code.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, got it, but in this case, how the hell is doing mozilla on MDN?
If I correctly understand your answer, this example shouldn't work neither isn't it?

[MDN - Mozilla Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Or I may have miss something :D I'm sorry, I'm quite a beginner with Js concepts and coding.

Comment: +1. To be more clearly, `addEventListener` requires *function* but OP passes `undefined` which is return value of `loadview`. Personally think *reference* is strange term in the JavaScript world.

Comment: @DrI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#JavaScript_Content MDN explains it perfectly, it uses something similar to my second example.

Comment: @LightStyle Wooo your edit and answer was so fast that I didn't get it the second example ;-)

Ok, now I perfectly understand it :D

Thank you very much folks.
What a hell fast and good quality answer, I do love you guys of SOF, you rocks :D

Comment: @LightStyle Updated my comment. I mean *function* is just *function* (exactly function *object*). There's no need for term *reference* IMHO. :)

Comment: @DrI you can do that in another way too, returning a function inside the `loadview` one. But it's something a bit more complex(not at all to be honest), so this way should be perfect for you :)

Comment: @Mics yes, it was just to explain what JS does when it requires a `function` passed as a parameter to another function. It is the same concept as callbacks, they are functions? Yes, but I'm used to say that they are reference to the functions themselves, since they're not exactly functions. I have a problem of terms unfortunately, I'd like to explain myself better but it's hard when your first language is english :P